# Obtaining pfSense graphs on another server

Tags: apache-2.4, pfsense, proxypass, check-mk

I'm trying to be able to get the traffic and system graphs from a pfSense router, which is only available on a specific management IP, onto my monitoring server in some way. So far I've thought of:

1. Try to export the graphs: won't look as nice, needs a bunch of work
2. Try to use apache2 to ProxyPass to the pfSense page: not working for various reasons (trying to ProxyPass just redirects instead, which obviously doesn't work if I'm outside of the network); this seems to be a pfSense-side problem, hence the question.

Really, all I want is to display that particular pfSense page in a "Frame" inside of Check_MK Multisite, with the monitoring server acting as a proxy so that I can view these graphs outside the management network. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were going to implement this, I'd probably create a limited-permissions user in pfsense and upload an ssh public key so that user can ssh to the pfsense router. With that functionality in place, you can easily write a script that periodically:

1. Uses scp/sftp to copy the rrd database files to another system.
2. Use the rrdtool command-line tools to generate graphs from the rrd databases.
3. Deploy the graphs to wherever you need them.

You could even browse the [PFsense source code](https://github.com/pfsense/pfsense) and to see the exact commands they're using to generate the graphs.

Comment: That seems like the most elegant solution. Part one I've got working, now to transplant the graph PHP code and make it work!

Comment: Good luck! Perhaps consider putting your solution on Github for others to use?

Comment: If I do get it working I will!